# Connect to Pi zero to Pi3 through wifi and share files

Tags: pi-3, ssh, pi-zero-w

Following setup:

- One RaspberryPi 3 which opens a wifi AP
- One Pi Zero W which connects directly to the hosted AP

Both run stretch, ssh is enabled.

This works so far, the pi zero connects to the pi3.

Now I want the pi zero to show pictures, which are stored on the Pi 3. I thought of using the feh viewer.

If I copy the pictures to the pi zero I can use feh like this:

```
usr/bin/feh -q -p -Z -F -R 10 -Y -D 10 /home/pi/Pictures
```

How is it possible to read the pictures directly from the Pi3 and show them. Like:

```
usr/bin/feh -q -p -Z -F -R 10 -Y -D 10 "Folder on the Pi3"
```

I have read of using samba to share a folder. But I can't believe there isn't a more easy and lightweight way. Any suggestions?

It worked with the suggested way using `ssh -X pi@ipadressofPI3` and then `feh /home/pi/TEST.jpg` Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, you will have to mount network drive somehow and then probably use the same technique to show your picture via feh. Other simpler way in my opinion would be copy files from RPi3 to local storage using scp command and show it from a local folder. If files changes dynamically on Rpi, you can right a script to periodically check files. Hope it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an image via ssh?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77895/how-to-display-an-image-via-ssh)

Comment: @Fabian: Thanks for the interesting link. As far as I understood this solution it shows every graphical content on the other display. In my case this wouldn't work, because the Pi3 itself shows some different content on the display connected to it.

Comment: @dhruvvyas90 The problem I see is that there is not enough space on the Pi Zero W, over the time the sd would be full of old files. Therefore I thought it would be better to get directly access to the Pi3 files. But maybe it's the easiest way to write a script for the PiZero which copies one file, shows it, deletes it, copies the next one, and so on. The best for this solution would be some sftp for python, maybe pysftp or paramiko, I will take a look

Answer (score 2):

The default way on linux to share directories over the network is to use the Network File System `nfs`. Support for this is integrated in the kernel so it should not be too difficult to set up. Because `Raspbian` is a flavor of `Debian` you can use [NFS Server Setup](https://wiki.debian.org/NFSServerSetup) from that.

Answer (score 1):

If `feh` is compiled with `libcurl` support (see version section of `man feh`) you can open HTTP URLs. So you can have a simple web server on your rpi3 providing the pictures in your network.