# How to see the picture you are about to take using USB webcam?

Tags: raspbian, camera

I know to take a picture you type into the command line: fswebcam name.jpg.
And a photo will be taken and saved to the file name.jpg.

But I want to see the picture I am taking. Like how you do it on a photo, you aim and shoot.

How can I do this on a Rasperry Pi 3B with a USB webcam?

Comment: For example `fswebcam -|display` The *display* tool is part of the ImageMagick (alternative: GraphicsMagick) package. You need to be more specific in your question and also, this question isn't very specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Nothing happen. It just said Writing JPEG image to '-'. What does that mean?

Comment: According to the manpage, it should write the captured image to *stdout*. The pipe symbol | then redirects *stdout* into *stdin* of the next program in the pipeline, *display*, which displays the received image data. But it seems the manpage of *fswebcam* is wrong then. Try without the *-*, maybe that works as intended with your version of *fswebcam*.

Comment: Do you use Raspbian Stretch Lite (try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78119/78211 ) or a desktop environment (which one)?

Comment: @Fabian, I use LXPanel 0.9.3

Answer (score 1):

You could use mplayer to watch the video stream, and press "s" to take a snapshot.

Comment: how to i download a launch the mplayer? what is the command for it?

Comment: "apt-get install mplayer".  I do have "deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free" in my /etc/apt/sources.list.  That is  "h t t p : / / www.deb-multimedia.org"

Comment: @mostvenerablesir In future please use a search engine *before* you ask a live human being to spend their time explaining things to you.  https://www.google.ca/search?q=mplayer

Comment: @goldilocks never mind, I won't be a live human being much longer.

Comment: I did google it. But I am totally new to raspberry pi and don't even know where all these commands come from. I did "apt-get install mplayer" but it tells me "could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock...are you root?" I followed the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/432154 but still couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: What is stretch main non-free?

Comment: only root can add new packages to your system.  You need to be "system administrator".   "stretch main non-free" indicates what debian version and kind of packages I want to retrieve from deb-multimedia.org.  Also, if you're that new, mplayer is not the right program for you, you should find an equivalent with a graphical interface. Perhaps the 3B can handle VLC.

Comment: I successfully downloaded mplayer  usind sudo. But I am not seeing a live video stream. I enter command "s" nothing happened.

Comment: Better have a look at a couple of these articles: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mplayer+watch+webcam&t=ftas&ia=web  and if you're not satisfied with the result, show exactly what command you tried. Just "mplayer" on its own won't do.